# I am not able to add "Assign using active assignment rules" check box of case object to my custom visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I am not able to add "Assign using active assignment rules" and "Send notification email to contact"

check box of case object to my custom visualforce page as like adding the standard pick list and fields

,not able find above check box in standard fields .so could you please help on .

Answer (score 1):

You need following code to execute assignment rules:

```
//Fetching the assignment rules on case
AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

//Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;

Case newCase = new Case(Status = 'New') ;
//Setting the DMLOption on Case instance
newCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
insert newCase ;
```

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/running-case-assignment-rules-from-apex

Comment: Hi Himanshu,Thanks for yours reply and time .Actually i am not overriding save button of case standard object,i only extending case standard controller.So i want to add check boxes  of  "Assign using active assignment rules" and "Send notification email to contact" case to my custom visual page.It should be work same as standard new case page.